# Configure ADP application to use a different database...?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, adp

I have an Access Project (ADP) that is currently configured to connect to an SQL Server 2000 database on one server.  I now need to migrate that server to SQL Server 2008 that will be on a different server.

Is it just a simple matter of modifying a connection string to point the application to the new database...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Open the database window in Access. 
>   Then go 'file' - 'connection'.  That
>   gives you the option to select the
>   server (item 1) & the database name
>   (item 3) (Item 2 being a valid login).

-- http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1362659

Answer (score 1):

From Access 2007, select the Office Button Server Connection which brings up the Data Link Properties window. From there you can select a specific SQL Server, type of security, and a specific database to connect to the Access 2007 ADP forms, etc. E.g. I can create a starter version of a specific database via a SQL Server restore, make changes in configuration table records in that database and then connect a new instance of an ADP or ADE file to that new database.