# View Connection String Information inside MS Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, connection-string

I have been given a task, which is the eventual re-write, but in the meantime, I need to document all that is going on.

We have an Access database that doesn't actually store any data.  The Access database is simply the UI (MS Access Forms) that a user uses and the data is actually maintained in a SQL Server database.  One thing I cannot seem to find is:  the connection string used for MS Access to connect to the SQL Server.  I need to find what database / server is used to store the information, but cannot seem to figure this out, nor has Google been able to give me the answers.  Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581049/configure-adp-application-to-use-a-different-database Found this answer.

Comment: And... did it help? For next time, please specify that you have an ADP project - this technique is outdated and hardly used anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the Immediate Window (Ctrl+G)

```
? CurrentDb.TableDefs("a_linked_table").Connect
```

will give the connect string.

Or open a table in design view and open the properties.

Comment: There are no tables in this Access database.  Just forms and some modules, so I cannot do that.

Comment: When I try the above in my Immediate Window, I get an error stating "Run-time error 91:  Object variable or with block variable not set".   I also cannot do CurrentProject.Connection.ConnectionString

Comment: Huh. No linked tables? Is this an ADP project? Maybe you have to delve into the code behind the forms to find how the data is loaded. @AMC

Comment: Yes, this is an ADP project.  I tried searching the forms to find the information, but can't seem to find the information.  The code does this:  Set db = CurrentProject.Connection, but I can't seem to find where it sets the connection.    Right mouse click and "definition" doesn't bring it up

Answer (score 0):

you can run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM msysobjects WHERE connect <> '';
```

the result is the list of the objects with a connection string that is not empty.

Comment: Are you saying inside SSMS or Access?

Comment: I know for sure that it works when run by Access itself; can't test it from SSMS though

Comment: `msysobjects` is an Access system table, so it will only work in Access. But without linked tables, I don't know if it will help. Perhaps there are Pass-Through queries.

Comment: @Andre I missed the latest comments to your answer: no linked tables = no output.